# getting parameter from the command line and fail to open file

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

FILE *fp;
printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
printf("%s\n", argv[2]);

fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

if((fp == NULL) || strcmp(argv[0], "MySearch") != 0)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "File is NULL ");
  fflush( stdout );
  exit(0);
}
```

in the command line I put

```
gcc Lab2.c -o MySearch
```

and then

```
./MySearch arr_file.txt 6
```

the function prints

```
./MySearch
arr_file.txt
6
File is NULL
```

There is a file called arr_file.txt, but why it failed to open it? Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to know why `fopen` fails, you should have the operating system tell you. `if ( fp == NULL ) { perror(argv[1]); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `argv[0]` is `"./MySearch"`
- which is different from `"MySearch"`
- so `strcmp()` returns non-zero
- so the `if` condition is satisfied irrespective of the value of `fp`.

Answer (score 0):

Your argv[0] is "./MySearch" not just "MySearch"
=>strcmp(argv[0], "MySearch") != 0

then your if condition ((fp == NULL) || strcmp(argv[0], "MySearch") != 0) would return true => the code block inside if is excuted with the Null file notification.

Just type "MySearch arr_file.txt 6" or remove/change strcmp(argv[0], "MySearch") != 0 from your if clause.

Answer (score 0):

- Your code is doing `strcmp("./MySearch", "MySearch)`, while will never evaluate to `0`. I recommend using:

  `const char *filename = "./MySearch";`

  and then doing:

  ```
  strcmp(argv[0], filename)
  ```
- Use `perror()` to get error messages from your OS, it will give better feedback.

Your code could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    const char *filename = "./MySearch";

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL || strcmp(argv[0], filename) != 0) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```